# PostgreSQL 9.3: Pass more than 100 arguments to `REPLACE` function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am passing around 1000 of arguments to the function `REPLACE`.

**Example**:

String contains some values:

```
 Declare
        str1 varchar = '1,2,3,4.................1000';
```

Now I want to replace the `,` with the `","` for which I am using the following
script:

```
 SELECT REPLACE(str1,',','","');
```

But getting an error:

**Error Detail**:

```
cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function
```

Comment: That error message can not be caused by the `replace()` function - at least not if you call it the way you have show us: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` function can search for only one string to replace.  You can look for multiple strings with the [`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) function.  This example replaces both `a` and `c` with nothing:

```
select regexp_replace('abc', '(a)|(c)', '', 'g');
-->
b
```

The `g` option stands for global, which allows multiple replacements.  Note that `regex_replace` can look for multiple strings, but is still limited to one replacement string.

Comment: But `SELECT REPLACE('1,2,3,4,5', ',', '","')` returns `1","2","3","4","5`

Comment: @struwi It does, but it can search for only one string to find and replace

Comment: Yes, that´s what was requested. To replace commas.

Comment: @struwi: I agree with you that in that case `replace` should work. As that solution is even in the question I assumed the OP was looking for different strings to find and replace.

Comment: @Andomar,Can you please help me for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855405/postgresql-9-3-dynamic-pivot-table-for-huge-records